# php fopen can't find file that definitely exists

Tags: php, fopen

I'm trying to load data from a CSV on my Windows PC into a database, something I've successfully done previously. `fopen` can't find my input file.

Here's the specific code I'm having trouble with:

```
<?php

ini_set('track_errors', '1');

$handle = fopen("C:/Users/Sam/Documents/test.csv", 'r') or die("can't open file: $php_errormsg");

?>
```

The error printed is:

> [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The file definitely exists, and I get the same problem on Unix machines. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are the file permissions set?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code, so it must be an issue related to your system. Does the user that runs PHP and/or your webserver have access to the file?

Comment: Have you tried using backslashes?

Comment: Mark-- not totally sure how to answer your question.  In this case I believe I'm the user running php, and I do indeed have access to the file.  Sam, I have tried using backslashes and double (escaped) backslashes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 (and Vista?) only lets a user access his own home directory and does not allow Apache (or other users) to. Unfortunately, this is a major headache, and I would suggest that you just move the file somewhere public.

This type of behavior is easier to fix in Linux, but you're still better off moving the file out of your directory into some path where Apache has read access.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, unfortunately, I still can't resolve the issue!  I've moved the file into the base directory C as well as made sure permissions are allowed for all users, but I'm still getting the "no such file" message, not even the "permission denied" message.  Very frustrating.

Comment: What happens when you put it in the same directory as the file?

Comment: cwallenpoole- that did it.  Either you are a genius or I'm really dumb.  I'd assumed the path was relative to my PC, not where the php script was.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to brag ;-)... I've been dealing with MAJOR Win7 permissions headaches for the past three or four days. It seemed like the natural cause. Just curious, which version of AMP are you using (XAMPP, WAMP, etc)?

Comment: I actually couldn't say.  This is only my second brush with the server, but it's hosted by my university and they say it's the Apache web server.  I don't really know more specifics than that, unfortunately.  Thanks again.