# PhpUnit has no access to public directory

Tags: php, pdf, testing, phpunit

I am using `Fdpi` to craft a pdf however I am using an external font (for chinese characters). My code works exactly as it should however php unit can not access my font in `app/public/fonts` directory.

```
    use setasign\Fpdi\Tfpdf\Fpdi;
    ...
    
    define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", public_path('fonts/'));
    
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pdf->AddFont('Code200365k', '', 'Code200365k.ttf', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Code200365k', '', 9);

    $pdf->Output($outputPath, "F");
```

This works totally fine when manually tested, with php unit I keep hitting

`ErrorException : fopen(/var/www/example-project/public/fonts/Code200365k.ttf): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

My test is very simple

```
$generator = new GeneratePdf();
$generator->generatePdf();
```

I have tried moving around my font in the directory with no luck, also gave www-data permission to my `public/fonts` but no luck. Anyone has any further ideas?

---Edit---

Turns out the issue is around fopen() 's permission issues as mentioned in [php fopen can't find file that definitely exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756547/php-fopen-cant-find-file-that-definitely-exists)

Comment: What is your own understanding of the _"Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"_ error message? Does the file `/var/www/example-project/public/fonts/Code200365k.ttf` exists on disk? What does the `$ file /var/www/example-project/public/fonts/Code200365k.ttf` command output?

Comment: I asserted `$this->assertFileExists(public_path('fonts/Code200365k.ttf'));` which shows green, so the file definitely is there with for phpunit.
I have also debugged  `fopen('/var/www/deftship-dev/public/fonts/Code200365k.ttf', 'r');` directly in the test and it seems it is an issue with fopen rather than phpunit

Comment: followed down looking at fopen() permission issues it appears that was definitely where this issue appears, didn't exactly find a solution but now I know where the problem is, thanks for guidance